# How would I loop through the parameters of two different objects in java, to show all possible combinations of said parameters?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, permutation

I'm not very good at this, but I am trying to create a program in Java that creates a polyhybrid cross punnett square from the parameters of two objects, which are the parents. every parameter is a string that is user defined with a scanner.

These are the two objects that I have, modified for the purpose of this question (they actually have seven strings parameters that are its genetic traits and they are all filled in by the user with scanner)

Creature Mom = new Creature("B,b");
Creature Dad = new Creature("C,c");

and I want to use a for loop to get the results "BC, bC, Bc, bc" in the console.

i know i need to use a delimiter or split somewhere to get those results, But I haven't really gotten to that point yet.

I've managed to create a punnett square with two arrays of strings that i loop through, as is seen here,

```
//accept user input
   Scanner alleles = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("enter first allele in mother's allele pair: ");
      Mom.alleleOne = alleles.nextLine();
      System.out.println("enter second allele in mother's allele pair: ");
      Mom.alleleTwo = alleles.nextLine(); 
      System.out.println("enter first allele in father's allele pair: ");
      Dad.alleleOne = alleles.nextLine();
      System.out.println("enter second allele in father's allele pair: ");
      Dad.alleleTwo = alleles.nextLine();
   //close scanner
   alleles.close();
   //arrays for parents data
   String[] Mother = {Mom.alleleOne, Mom.alleleTwo};
   String[] Father = {Dad.alleleOne, Dad.alleleTwo};
   //display data
   System.out.println("Mother Result: " + Arrays.toString(Mother));
   System.out.println("Father Result: " + Arrays.toString(Father));
   System.out.println("Possible children: ");
   // for loop to cycle through combinations
   for (int i = 0; i < Mother.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < Father.length; j++) {
         System.out.println(Mother[i] + Father[j]);

      }
    }//end for
```

But i really think continuing with objects is my best bet here for continuing this project. I've thought about using reflection, and turning an object into an array of its fields/parameters, but nothing seems to click in my mind. I hope what I'm asking makes sense, I apologize if it doesn't. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It’s not clear why reflection would be helpful. Split the string on commas, create the permutations. Which part is causing the issue?

Comment: I was reccomended to use reflection as a way of "getting" the declared fields of the object i believe, to put them in an array and then cycle through them to get the permutations using a for loop. I know split automatically puts its results in an array, so was I just thinking about this way harder than I should have?

Comment: Why complicate things with reflection? In your example you use the values of the fields in the object. Just create a method in your class to return those values as array - `public String[] getAlleles() { return new String[] {field1, field2}; }`

Comment: Would i still be able to do something like this even if the fields become arrays of two strings due to the split method being used?

Comment: Without much context it's difficult to provide meaningful help. Do all implementations have two alleles? *(Tangential: any time there's variables w/ numeric part names a collection might be a better choice, e.g., a `Creature` would have a `List<Allele>`, which in this case might just be `List<String>`, but the idea is the same.)*

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought I gave enough context. When you ask if all implementations have two alleles, are you asking if every object has only one string? because the string of the Mom creature has two alleles, just seperated by a comma...What I want to do is seperate them with split, and then possibly put them in an array of strings and then loop through them. I can do that, right? I'm sorry. I don't know where else to ask for help, and I don't think I'm good at giving enough information...

Comment: @este Just combine the resulting arrays into one. Or combine them into a `List` so you don't have to copy the contents manually.

Comment: @Chaosfire i'll try that and see where it gets me, thank you deeply.

Comment: @este When I ask if all implementations *(of `Creature`)* will have two alleles I'm asking if each impl will have two alleles. *(Allele representation is unrelated to combining/permuting them.)* It's not clear what specific issue you're having, but reflection at this point seems unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, they will. Sorry, I got a bit confused. The issue im having is, I just didn't really know how to get the final "permutation results" from a bunch of string parameters in an object, which will then be turned into a bunch of arrays due to the split method. I know how to loop through two arrays of strings, but not how to loop through parameters in an object that get split into arrays of strings.